# Mocking jdbctemplate with param map

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock the call to jdbctemplate.query using Mockito for the below line of code

```
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, paramMap, (rs, rowNum) -> rowMapper(rs))
```

where the parameters are String, Map and ResultSetExtractor respectively

When I try to mock it using Mockito, I am running into compilation error, below is the code in the unit test

```
when(jdbcTemplate.query(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyMap(), ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
....
}
```

The error I am getting is

> Cannot resolve method query(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, T)

Comment: Are you talking about the [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) class from spring? I don't really see one with that signature.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito handles very badly the generics, since is not compiled
try replacing the any() by any(ResultSetExtractor.class)

```
when(jdbcTemplate.query(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.anyMap(), ArgumentMatchers.any(ResultSetExtractor.class))).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
....
}
```

Comment: ah, try to match eq(TheRealPassedObject)

Comment: see this http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#Wildcards